# Transporting woodwind instruments at low temperatures

Tags: oboe, transportation

For the coming season I am facing the problem that I have to get my double-reed instruments from my home to the rehearsal location and back, while it can get way below zero outside (-20° C). I will be outside usually for ~30 min. My biggest problem here is that the onliest protection the instruments get is their bag, due to not having a backpack which is large enough (their bag still provides some damping). Furthermore my current habit is not to dry them directly after the rehearsal, but rather let them dry on their own at home, after opening the case.
Thus, could the low temperatures damage my instruments, and if yes, what could I do to prevent that?

Comment: Specifically, which double reed instruments?

Comment: Oboe/Cor Anglais

Comment: Degrees are Celsius/centigrade?

Comment: @guidot: Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest risk here is from ice forming in your instrument. Swabbing will lower the risk, but even the most careful swab won't get all the moisture, and some of the water will be inside the wood itself. If that freezes, it expands and you've got a fairly high risk of cracking the instrument. It's unlikely the case alone provides sufficient insulation to keep your oboe above freezing for 30 minutes when the temperature is significantly below freezing.

I'd strongly recommend an insulated bag and a source of heat inside the bag, like a chemical hand or foot warmer. Reusable ones are available, to avoid the expense and waste of single use ones. Cold days might require a couple of warmers, but experimentation will show you what's sufficient. That way, you know that the instrument isn't going to get below freezing.

Comment: I would be concerned that having a heat source inside the bag or case would create hot spots & cold spots.  Having thermal gradients like these also causes stress on objects, since the hotter parts of the object will "want" to expand more than colder parts.

Comment: Chemical handwarmers are not particularly hot. I wouldn't use it in the case touching the instrument without more research, but with the warmer in the bag, the thickness of the case should be sufficient to prevent a hot spot on the instrument itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore my current habit is not to dry them directly after the
>   rehearsal, but rather let them dry on their own at home, after opening
>   the case.

I would recommend changing that habit. There was a story in the UK news recently of a player who acquired a fatal lung infection from the bugs breeding in his uncleaned instruments. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-37152871

Air is a pretty good thermal insulator. I wouldn't expect the instrument itself to come to much harm unless you change its temperature *quickly* - e.g. warm it up over a hot-air vent when you get to the rehearsal room, rather than just letting it warm up naturally in the air.

I would suggest you carry the *reeds* in a pocket in your clothes, so your body heat keeps them at a more stable temperature.

Comment: The reason for that habit comes from my oboe merchant, who discouraged the cleaning. He told me that by cleaning the oboe the interior will be slightly damaged each time, which then could change the tone easily after multiple cleaning sessions. Is that correct?

Comment: I am a recorder player so I have lots of small tubes of wood around. I also let them dry naturally, w/out swabbing. Not been a problem as far as I can tell. If the cases have any kind of insulation, 30 minutes in subzero shouldn't be a problem.  I agree also with the reeds comment. I will sometimes carry my headjoints on my person for that reason. Using wool socks is something many professionals do.

Comment: Carpid wanted to comment: Also you might be interested in "green line" oboes. I have been playing one for several years now and am really happy with it. They became pretty popular lately. These oboes consist of 95% grenadilla wood powder with carbon fibers which makes them a lot more durable especially when it comes to temperatures. Of course buying a new instrument probably isn't the answer for your problem right now, but if you ever consider buying a new one I can recommend a green line one if you still have trouble with low temperatures.
http://www.blackwoodconservation.org/greenline.html